# async/await with firebase .on() database listener

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, async-await, react-redux

I'm designing a messaging application with redux as my state manager and firebase to store my data. I've started writing my database listeners in this fashion:

```js
const fetchMessages = roomKey => async dispatch => {
  const db = firebase.database();
  let { messages } = await db.ref(`messages/${roomKey}`).on('value');
dispatch({
  type: SET_MESSAGES,
  payload: messages,
})
```

};

All this basically does is fetch messages by a room key and then dispatch an action that sets the messages in the redux state.

Traditionally, this would be written as such:

```
db.ref(`messages/${roomKey}`).on('value', snapshot => {
  const messages = snapshot.messages;
  dispatch({
    type: SET_MESSAGES,
    payload: messages,
  })
});
```

And everytime something changes in `messages/${roomKey}`, my dispatch function would be executed. I'm wondering if this will work the same using the async await syntax, and if not, how I could make it work.

Hope this was enough detail!

Comment: [`on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) does not return a promise. `once` does, but `on` does not.

Comment: If you want to throw that in an answer Ill upvote you! That answered my question perfectly and gave me one of those "of course" moments.

Comment: Thanks. I got the same "of course" moments, followed by a facepalm to myself.

Answer (score 9):

The reference's [`on` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) does not return a promise. The callback it's passed can be invoked multiple times, so a promise does not fit with the method's contract.

However, the reference's [`once` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method does return a promise, as the (optional) callback it's passed is invoked only once - after which the promise resolves. The `once` method is likely the one you want to use.